# Multiply key of the same dict

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, list-comprehension, dict-comprehension

I'm using python 3.5,
I need to multiply this dict and this should output the result of multiplication  of each key of dict.

```
{0: [0.0008726003490401396, 0.004363001745200698, 0.0008726003490401396, 0.0008726003490401396, 0.0017452006980802793, 0.008726003490401396, 0.0008726003490401396, 0.0017452006980802793, 0.0008726003490401396, 0.0017452006980802793, 0.0017452006980802793, 0.0008726003490401396, 0.0008726003490401396], 1: [0.007853403141361256, 0.008726003490401396, 0.0008726003490401396], 2: [0.004363001745200698, 0.0008726003490401396, 0.0008726003490401396, 0.0017452006980802793, 0.0008726003490401396, 0.0008726003490401396, 0.007853403141361256, 0.0008726003490401396, 0.0008726003490401396, 0.0008726003490401396, 0.002617801047120419, 0.0008726003490401396, 0.0008726003490401396, 0.0008726003490401396, 0.0017452006980802793, 0.0008726003490401396, 0.0008726003490401396, 0.0008726003490401396, 0.0017452006980802793, 0.0008726003490401396, 0.0008726003490401396, 0.0008726003490401396, 0.0008726003490401396, 0.0008726003490401396, 0.0008726003490401396, 0.008726003490401396, 0.0008726003490401396, 0.0008726003490401396, 0.0008726003490401396, 0.0008726003490401396, 0.0008726003490401396, 0.002617801047120419, 0.0008726003490401396, 0.0008726003490401396, 0.0017452006980802793, 0.0008726003490401396, 0.0008726003490401396, 0.0008726003490401396, 0.002617801047120419, 0.0034904013961605585, 0.0008726003490401396, 0.0008726003490401396, 0.0008726003490401396, 0.002617801047120419, 0.0008726003490401396, 0.0034904013961605585, 0.0008726003490401396, 0.0008726003490401396, 0.0008726003490401396, 0.0008726003490401396]}
```

This is my try but does not work:

```
lista = {k: [v*v for v in v] for k, v in lista.items()}
```

the output i would is for example:

```
{0: [0.068726003490401396], 1: [0.077853403141361256, 2: [0.098363001745200698]}
```

Comment: instead of inner list comprehension, look into python's 'reduce' function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using dictionary comprehension and [`functools.reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce) + [`operator.mul`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.mul):

```
>>> from functools import mul
>>> mul(3, 4)  # == 3 * 4
12

>>> from functools import reduce
>>> reduce(mul, [3, 4, 2])  # == (3 * 4) * 2
24
```

---

```
>>> from functools import reduce
>>> from operator import mul
>>>
>>> lista = {
...     0: [0.0008726003490401396, 0.004363001745200698],
...     1: [0.007853403141361256, 0.008726003490401396, 0.0008726003490401396],
...     2: [0.004363001745200698, 0.0008726003490401396, 0.0008726003490401396],
... }
>>>
>>> {key: reduce(mul, value) for key, value in lista.items()}
{0: 3.8071568457248673e-06, 1: 5.979827506374137e-08, 2: 3.322126392430076e-09}
>>> {key: [reduce(mul, value)] for key, value in lista.items()}
{0: [3.8071568457248673e-06], 1: [5.979827506374137e-08], 2: [3.322126392430076e-09]}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer..but 0.0008726003490401396*0.004363001745200698= isn't the result of the moltiplication..

Comment: @DavideDiMenna, Then, could you elaborate how the expected values are calculated?

Comment: you are right man! Now i try to do it.. Isn't a way without import?

Comment: @DavideDiMenna, You can replace `mul` with `lambda a, b: a * b`. But reduce should be imported in Python 3.x.

Comment: omg thank you man, im implementing  a spam filter... I shoul reuse it :D The problem will be applay bayes function for each key of dict..

Comment: Thanks a lot.. But if want to mutiply each element of the list  written by the function you wrote by a float?

Comment: @DavideDiMenna, I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: {0: [3.8071568457248673e-06], 1: [5.979827506374137e-08], 2: [3.322126392430076e-09]} all these element mutiplyed by 0.5 .. output would  be {0: [3.8071568457248673e-06*0.5], 1: [5.979827506374137e-08*0.5], 2: [3.322126392430076e-09*0.5]}

Comment: @DavideDiMenna, `reduce(..)` -> `reduce(..) * 0.5` seems what you want.

Comment: i have done by my self now i should apply the bayes theorem with this method.. Impossibile that i could  solve it.. Do you now how to sum two dictionaries?